# How to get an integer from slice of bytearray?

Tags: python, python-3.3

I need to get an integer from two bytes in a `bytearray` from position x. What is the best way to do this?

I thought the following would work:

```
>>> a = bytearray((1, 1, 1))
>>> int.from_bytes(a[1:2], 'little')
1
```

But I expected 32896 (i.e. 1000000010000000) Or if I have got my endianness mixed up: 257 (i.e. 0000000100000001). But not 1!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a[1:2]` is just a single byte (length 1)

Did you mean `a[0:2]` or `a[1:3]` perhaps?

The endianness won't matter as all the bytes are the same. result should be 257

Comment: duh! im such a noob! I did mean a[1:3], thanks. Also would you say this is the best way to do what I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [9]: a[1:2]
Out[9]: bytearray(b'\x01')


In [11]: a[:2]
Out[11]: bytearray(b'\x01\x01')
```

:)